# Swift, number of threads in app

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift

I am making an app for website. I use JSON to get data. I want to load all posts in threads (1 post - 1 thread). How many threads I can make? Should I control the number of threads?

Comment: Why do you want to load just one post per thread? The overhead in spawning and later joining one thread per post will be large. For that matter, why do you want to use threads directly? Have you looked into [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html)?

Comment: Hello  Riley Avron! Thank you for the answer. Can you tell me the difference between GCD and NSThread?

Comment: GCD is a abstraction for concurrent code execution, especially on multicore systems. An NSThread is an Objective-C class that represents a thread. GCD manages threads on your behalf to try to execute concurrent code as efficiently as possible. For more information, read the relevant documentation.

Comment: Thank you! Will try GCD. But, I want to use minimum 10 threads at the same time, because i want to make fast loading app. So, iOS has something like FIFO threads? Application becomes very difficult and I am afraid that the number of threads will increase. Can the threads automatically replace each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Cocoa you usually don't work with Threads directly. Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) is an API that handles this for your. You just have to partition your task into small managable chunks, dispatch them onto a background queue and the rest is handled for you. You don't need to worry about creating threads, how many are currently running etc. When you dispatch enough work on one (or possibly more) queues, the CPU is going to run at maximum load.

You can also use NSOperationQueue, which has the ability to throttle the execution to some extend or cancel currently running tasks (not possible with GCD).

Unless you are doing anything unusual there is no need to use NSThread directly. Use GCD when you just need to perform a simple small task asynchronously. Use NSOperationQueue when you need more control, like cancelling submitted tasks or setting priorities. It's API is also a bit higher level and in Objective-C. GCD is a C level API, so for example it can't catch ObjC-Exceptions. NSOperationQueue uses GCD internally, so both should work equally well.

Comment: Thank you! But I can't understand the difference between  NSOperationQueue, NSthread and GCD. Can you explain? Right now I use NSthread.